# Lock (uneditable) Textfield and Textbox after filling (hyperref)

Tags: hyperref

I would like to lock textboxes and textfields after filling them.

Is there a way to do this ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{eforms}

\begin{document}

\CheckBox[height=0.3cm, width=0.3cm]{CheckBox}{}\\

\TextField[width=4cm]{TextField}{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @samcarter Done :)

Comment: By "lock" do you mean that you do not want the fields to be editable?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Exactly.